# ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `load_and_authorize_resource' for UserAccountsController:Class):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new at Ruby on Rails and i'm trying to find a solution for this.
i have a Controller that starts like this:

```
class UserAccountsController < ApplicationController
    include Concerns::UserFinancialContext
    load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:change_contract, :show_modal_simulator_invoice, :project_member_info, :new_account_in_modal, :user_view]
```

I also have a .rb file in here:

```
app/controllers/concerns/user_financial_context.rb
```

and finally

```
app/doc/Concerns/UserFinancialContext.html
```

But the following error appears:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `load_and_authorize_resource' for UserAccountsController:Class):
  app/controllers/user_accounts_controller.rb:3:in `<class:UserAccountsController>'
  app/controllers/user_accounts_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

Any idea how it could be fixed?

Comment: `load_and_authorize_resource` comes from CanCan gem. Did you set it up properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn to read error messages.

From error message you provided your program trying to call a method that has not been defined. Ruby is an interpreted language and every method you call should be defined beforehead.

When you call a method without explicit receiver ruby sends it to `self` object. Inside a body of a class definition `self` is the class itself. In this case it is `UserAccountsController`.

From the name of the method I assume that it is actually supposed to be provided by either [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)  gem. If you look in this source file (which is documented well): [controller_additions.rb](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb) you'll see method definition:

```
module ControllerAdditions
  module ClassMethods
    def load_and_authorize_resource(*args)
      cancan_resource_class.add_before_filter(self, :load_and_authorize_resource, *args)
    end
  end
end
```

And later how that method is made available to `ApplicationController` from which your `UserAccountsController` is inherited:

```
if defined? ActionController::Base
  ActionController::Base.class_eval do
    include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
  end
end
```

Now you generally want to add that gem to your project and that's made according to gem docs by including it in your project's `Gemfile`with

```
gem 'cancancan'
```

line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Rails in [API-only mode](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html) and needed to modify my ApplicationController to include CanCan::ControllerAdditions, as it inherited from ActionController::API:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    include CanCan::ControllerAdditions
```

Other controllers inherit from this one, for example:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

This is to work around [the 'elsif'](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/cf9aa5792c1ac41b306848931b45dd94f3592e8e/lib/cancan/controller_additions.rb#L391) which adds the additions to ActionController::Base and not ActionController::API, even though both are defined in my app (via gem actionpack)