# Simple_token_authentication routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, devise, rails-api

I'm attempting to use the following gem ['simple_token_authentication'](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication/) however I get the following error `undefined method acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for' for DevicesController:Class` [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22733098/actioncontrollerroutingerror-undefined-method-load-and-authorize-resource-f) question would suggest this is a lack of gem issue however simple_token_authentication is in my gemfile and I have run `bundle update` and `bundle install` confirming version 1.6.0 of the gem is installed and restarted the server.

little confused help appreciated!

**Controller**

```
class DevicesController < ApplicationController
  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

  def index
   @devices = GpsDevice.all
   render json: @devices
 end
end
```

**user model**

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_token_authenticatable

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end
```

**route.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  match 'trackers', to: 'devices#index', via: 'get', :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
end
```

may or may not be relevant I'm using rails-api rather than rails

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your ApplicationController:

```
extend SimpleTokenAuthentication::ActsAsTokenAuthenticationHandler
```

Or use ApplicationController::Base.